# Difference between ASM/C++ and Python when NEG unsigned 1

Tags: python

I recently stumbled at an error which is present only in Python.
Negating unsigned 1 does not equal FFFFFFFF.

In Assembler:

```
MOV(eax, 0x1)
NEG(eax)
```

> Result is 0xffffffff

Same result in C++

In Python however:

```
import numpy as np
print(hex(~np.uint32(1)))
```

> Result is 0xfffffffe

What am I missing here?

Comment: But `~` is not the negation operator, it's bitwise-inversion

Comment: Thats not what the wiki says  
~ x
Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1

Comment: That's an other way to explain the same thing, also equivalently you could say that `~x` is `-1 - x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In two's complement arithmetic, negation requires taking the bitwise inversion of a number (which is what `~` does) and adding one to it.

```
print(hex(~np.uint32(1) + 1))
```

Or you could use Python's negation operator:

```
print(hex(-np.uint32(1)))
```

Comment: So you are saying that in Python ~n = -n - 1 while in C its ~n = -n?

Comment: @Involar no, in C it is NOT ~n = -n.  Read more about [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  The NEG instruction is not the same as bit inversion.